# How do I get a value from a selected Spinner item that loads a ListPreference?

Tags: android, button, spinner, listpreference

So this is my situation...

I have a Spinner with Parking Zones... Zone 1, Zone 2 etc.

What I want to do: when user clicks a Button "Send SMS Message", the Button should load a Parking Zone phone number into an SMS message. The Parking Zone number is set depending on the Parking Zone selection from the Spinner.

---

I completely edited my initial question... So I have...

Spinner with Parking Zones:

```
final Spinner spinner_zona = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerZona);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.zone, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_zona.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

spinnerPrefs with Parking zones phone numbers:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="spinnerZone_postavke">
    <item>700101</item>
    <item>700102</item>
    <item>700103</item>
    <item>700105</item>
    <item>700104</item>
</string-array>
```

Storing and retrieving phone numbers in SharedPreferences:

```
 public static boolean setPreferences(Context c, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences("com.example.igor.parkingzagreb.Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    return editor.commit();


}

public static String getPreference(Context c, String key) {
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences("com.example.igor.parkingzagreb.Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String value = settings.getString(key, "");
    return value;
```

---

Am I on the right track? What is the next step in order to push those Phone numbers to an SMS message via a Button click?

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can put a Hashmap with name-phone number and then search the phone searching by spinner name

Comment: @D4rWiNS I updated the OP with your suggestion. Can you check it out please? Thanks.

Comment: @IgorGajic Where did you store the phone numbers?

Comment: @iRuth In the values folder, spinnerPrefs.xml file as items inside a string-array.

Comment: @IgorGajic Please post the source code of the activity that contains the `Spinner` as well as spinnerPrefs.xml.

Comment: @iRuth I updated the initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Button`s `onClick` method, you can implement the `SmsManager`, like below.

You can either use the SmsManager API:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNumber", null, "message", null, null);
```

Or, you could use the built in SMS application:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content"); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Using the SmsManager API approache requires a permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Example using `SmsManager` in your `Button`s `onClick` method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //Fetch your selected zone from the spinner
    String zone = spinner_zona.getSelectedItem().toString();

    //Set the receipt phone number here, e.g. from SharedPreferences
    String phoneNo = "yourPhoneNumber"      

    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, zone, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "SMS faild, please try again later!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Find more details [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/).

Comment: Amazing stuff @Marcus.
I didn't mention one thing tho. The user should enter his Regplate number into an EditText, and then send an SMS via the Send SMS button. How can I accomplish that?
I mean, this is probably a complicated one for a beginner like me, but I need to learn somehow... Thanks.

Comment: You change spinner_zona.getSelectedItem().toString(); to your_edit_text.getText().toString(); in your onClick. Same thing as when you fetch the value of the spinner. Hope this helps, and if it was helpful please tick it as the accepted answer :-) @Igor Gajic